# Multiple RestController are not getting called from Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am trying a build a Spring Boot Rest Application using two different Rest Controller. 
I am seeing that DestinationController is getting called, whereas CustomerController is not.

Need your help to sort this out.

Package Structure
[image]

Please find the RestController Code

Destination Conrollr Code:

```
package com.ayan.tourismSystem.controller.rest;

import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.ayan.tourismSystem.entity.Destination;
import com.ayan.tourismSystem.entity.wrapper.DestinationWrapper;
import com.ayan.tourismSystem.service.DestinationService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/api/destination")
public class DestinationController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DestinationController.class);

    @Autowired
    private DestinationService destinationService;

    /**
     * @author Ayan Bhattacharyya
     * @param region
     * @return Destination List by region
     */
    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET, value="/region/{region}")
    public List<Destination> getDestinationByRegion(
            @PathVariable(value="region")String region){
        return this.destinationService.getDestinationByRegion(region);
    }

    /**
     * @author Ayan Bhattacharyya
     * @param country
     * @return Destination List by country
     */
    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET, value="/country/{country}")
    public List<Destination> getDestinationByCountry(
            @PathVariable(value="country")String country){
        return this.destinationService.getDestinationByCountry(country);
    }

    /**
     * @author Ayan Bhattacharyya 
     * @param destinationDetails(Destination Name, Destination Country, Destination Region)
     * @return Destination Id (Created)
     */
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/addDestination")
    public Long addDestination(@RequestBody DestinationWrapper addDestination) {
        logger.info("Add destination Service Call Started");
        if (addDestination != null) {
            String name = addDestination.getDestination().getDestinationName();
            String country = addDestination.getDestination().getCountry();
            String region = addDestination.getDestination().getRegion();

            logger.info("Values before passing to service " + name + " " + country + " " + region);
            Destination addedDestination = this.destinationService.addDestination(name, country, region);

            Long response = addedDestination.getDestinationId();

            return response;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/updateDestination")
    public Long updateDestination(@RequestBody DestinationWrapper addDestination) {
        logger.info("Update Destination Call Started");
        if (addDestination != null) {
            Long destinationId = addDestination.getDestination().getDestinationId();
            String name = addDestination.getDestination().getDestinationName();
            String country = addDestination.getDestination().getCountry();
            String region = addDestination.getDestination().getRegion();

            logger.info("Values before passing to service " + destinationId + " " + name + " " + country + " " + region);
            Destination addedDestination = this.destinationService.updateDestination(destinationId, name, country, region);

            Long response = addedDestination.getDestinationId();

            return response;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/deleteDestination/{destinationId}")
    public void deleteDestination(@PathVariable(value="destinationId")String destinationId) {
        logger.info("Delete Destination Call Started");

            logger.info("Values before passing to service " + destinationId);
            Long id = Long.valueOf(destinationId);
            this.destinationService.deleteDestination(id);
    }
}
```

Customer Controller Code

```
package com.ayan.tourismSystem.controller.rest;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.ayan.tourismSystem.entity.Customer;
import com.ayan.tourismSystem.entity.wrapper.CustomerWrapper;
import com.ayan.tourismSystem.service.CustomerService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(name = "/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerController.class);

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    /**
     * @author Ayan Bhattacharyya 
     * @param destinationDetails(Destination Name, Destination Country, Destination Region)
     * @return Destination Id (Created)
     */
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/addCustomer")
    public Long addCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerWrapper addCustomer) {
        logger.info("Add Customer Call Started");
        if (addCustomer != null) {
            String firstName = addCustomer.getCustomer().getFirstName();
            String middleName = addCustomer.getCustomer().getMiddleName();
            String lastName = addCustomer.getCustomer().getLastName();
            String email = addCustomer.getCustomer().getEmail();
            String mobile = addCustomer.getCustomer().getMobile();
            String address = addCustomer.getCustomer().getAddress();
            String state = addCustomer.getCustomer().getAddress();
            String country = addCustomer.getCustomer().getCountry();
            String postcode = addCustomer.getCustomer().getPostcode();
            String travelDocumentType = addCustomer.getCustomer().getTravelDocumentType();
            String travelDocumentNumber = addCustomer.getCustomer().getTravelDocumentNumber();

            Customer customer = this.customerService.addCustomer(firstName, middleName, 
                    lastName, email, mobile, address, state, country, 
                    postcode, travelDocumentType, travelDocumentNumber);
            if(customer != null){
                return customer.getCustomerId();
            }
            else{
                return null;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Spring Application Code

```
package com.ayan.tourismSystem;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.ayan.*"})
public class TourismSystemApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TourismSystemApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Please suggest me what I am missing /doing incorrect here.

Thanks in Advance!
Ayan Bhattacharyya

Comment: what is the url that you use to call APIs in CustomerController?

Comment: Can you show how do you call these `API` methods? What the error du you have? `40*` or `50*`?

Comment: no need to add _scanBasePackages = {"com.ayan.*"}_ and if you add a package(s),  leave out the .* at the end

Comment: Hello @sidgate,

Please find the URL I am firing from postman. Also I can't see any logs in console. I have aslo tested that when I put this code in DestinationController class, it is working fine.

Comment: @sidgate

URL - http://localhost:8080/customer/addCustomer

Request Body:
{
 "customer":
 {
  "customerId": null,
  "firstName": "Alison",
  "middleName": " ",
  "lastName": "Madison",
  "mobile": "+61 434657890",
  "email": "alison.madison@gmail.com",
  "address": "990 Hay Street, West Perth",
  "state": "WA",
  "country": "Australia",
  "postcode": "6005",
  "travelDocumentType": "Driving Licence",
  "travelDocumentNumber": "AB990878"
 }
}

Comment: @sidgate

Response;

{
    "timestamp": "2019-03-04T06:29:19.645+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/customer/addCustomer"
}

Comment: @DirkDeyne

I have removed scanBasePackagaes. However, it's still not calling second controller.

Comment: @MichałZiober - Just added the error in the comment.
It is 404 Not Found Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using incorrect attribute in `RequestMapping` to define the URL mapping

```
@RequestMapping(name = "/customer")
```

should be replaced with

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer")
```

or just

```
@RequestMapping("/customer")
```

`name` attribute just assigns a name to the mapping, while `value` specifies the URL mapping

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;** You do not need to add `scanBasePackages` since spring will look for all sub-folders based on the location of your main class.

**Explanation:**

Spring boot scan components starting from the folder where your `@SpringBootApplication` class is located, following all sub-folders.

> A single **@SpringBootApplication** annotation can be used to enable
>   those three features, that is: *@EnableAutoConfiguration, @ComponentScan, @Configuration*.
>
> **@ComponetScan** enable *@Component* scan on the package where the
>   application is located.